# Terraform create an app service plan after every x app service

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I make use of the Terraform Azure provider to deploy a large list of webapps into appservice plans.

The list of webapps is setup like this:

```
applist = [
"app1",
"app2",
"app3",
"app4",
"app5",
"app6",
"app7",
"app8",
"app9",
"app10",
"app11",
"app12",
"app13",
"app14"
]
```

is it possible with terraform to create a new appservice plan after every 5th app?

I should end up with something like this:

```
appserviceplan01(
"app1",
"app2",
"app3",
"app4",
"app5"
)
appserviceplan02(
"app6",
"app7",
"app8",
"app9",
"app10"
)
appserviceplan03(
"app11",
"app12",
"app13",
"app14
)
```

Comment: Updated my question to explain it better

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your list as a map then you use a for-Each loop to create the plan resource by dividing by 5 on the key

something like this...

```
variable "app_service_object" {  
  default = {
1 ="app1"
2 = "app2"
3 = "app3"
4 = "app4"
5 = "app5"
6 = "app6"
7 = "app7"
 } 
  
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "game" {
  name     = var.resource_group_name
  location = var.resource_group_location
}



resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "game" {
  for_each            = tomap(var.app_service_object)  
  name                = "${var.app_service_plan_name}-${floor(tonumber(each.key) / 5)}"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.game.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.game.name
  kind                = "Linux"
  reserved            = true

  sku {
    tier = "Basic"
    size = "B1"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_app_service" "game" {
   for_each            = tomap(var.app_service_object)   

   name                = "${var.app_service_name_prefix}-${each.value}"
   location            = azurerm_resource_group.game.location
   resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.game.name
   app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.game[tostring(each.key)].id

  site_config {
   // your site config
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort.
it starts ceating a lot of app service plans and then it stops on duplicates?

Comment: Plans must be created before app service.  Look at terraform plan command results and you'll see that it's same name for every 5 app plan

Comment: your code is solid, it only breaks if i try to adjust it to my specific scenario

Comment: found it, if the is list longer the deployment breaks

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution on this page :
https://azurecitadel.com/automation/terraform/lab4/

the locals, which contains a chunklist, creates groups with a max of 20 apps,
the output is used to create appservice plans with count, and with element() the apps are distrubuted over the appservice plans

```
variable "app_service_object" {
  default = [
    "app1",
    "app2",
    "app3",
    "app4",
    "app5",
    "app6",
    "app7",
    "app8",
    "app9",
    "app10",
    "app11",
    "app12",
    "app13",
    "app14",
     ...
    "app100"
  ]
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "game" {
  name     = var.resource_group_name
  location = var.resource_group_location
}

locals {
  webappsperloc = [
    for name in chunklist(var.app_service_object, 20) : name
  ]
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "game" {
  count               = length(local.webappsperloc)
  name                = "${var.app_service_plan_name}${count.index}"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.game.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.game.name

  sku {
    tier = "Basic"
    size = "B1"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_app_service" "game" {
  count               = length(var.app_service_object)
  name                = "${var.app_service_object[count.index]}-azure-web"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.game.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.game.name
  app_service_plan_id = element(azurerm_app_service_plan.game.*.id, count.index)

  site_config {
    // your site config
  }

}
```